# Displaying Column Graphs in Power BI, displays only 20 values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I created a stacked column chart in Power BI. It displays data from FB in my scenario. 
My x-axis displays the month and year and the y-axis displays the total number of posts on that month. 
It displays only 20 months whereas my data has more than 20 months. 
Is there a limit or how do I display all months here!!

[image]

Comment: No limit to show already imported data from FB as we can see YearAndMonth showing on filter. Could you share the data to take a look? (mainly M code)

Comment: I am a newbie in powerBI, are you asking for the query what is M code?

Comment: Yes, Your query. FYI.. Power query language also called M language.

Comment: let
    Source = Facebook.Graph("graph.facebook.com/v2.8/Me/posts"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"message", "created_time", "id", "story"}),
    ParseYearAndMonth = (someText as text) as text => DateTimeZone.ToText(DateTimeZone.From(someText), "yyyy MMMM"),
    invokedFunction = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "yearAndMonth", each ParseYearAndMonth([created_time]), type text)
in
    invokedFunction